# jbehave regex in step name

Tags: java, regex, jbehave

How can I map following different steps to single java method?

```
    Then 1st message should be ...
    Then 2nd message should be ...
    Then 3rd message should be ...
    Then 15th message should be ...

    @Then("$ord(st|nd|rd|th) message should be ...")
    public void assertMessage(int ord) {...}
```

Why `(st|nd|rd|th)` is not working?

Comment: Hmm what is "ord" doing there? Also thats a regex embedded in some sort of DSL?

Comment: ord is ordinal number of the message - int parameter

Answer (score 0):

I think they are two ways to realize this with Jbehave and Java:

1.) You add a whitespace between number and (st|nd|rd|th) so Jbehave can easily recognize them:

```
 @Then("$var {st|nd|rd|th} message should be ...")
 public void assertMessage(int var) {
    System.out.println("VAR:"+var);
 }
```

so your story is:

```
 Then 1 st message should be ...
 Then 2 nd message should be ...
 Then 3 rd message should be ...
 Then 15 th message should be ...
```

2.) You read the number and the annotation and perform a  substring function assuming that you always want to remove the last two chars:

```
@Then("$var message should be ...")
public void assertMessage(String var) {
   int nr = Integer.parseInt(var.substring(0, var.length()-2));
   System.out.println("VAR:"+nr);
}
```

so you can keep your story like:

```
 Then 1st message should be ...
 Then 2nd message should be ...
 Then 3rd message should be ...
 Then 15th message should be ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your story just a little, then this becomes pretty easy.  It doesn't really require any special regex in the step name.

```
Then message 1 should be ...
Then message 2 should be ...
Then message 3 should be ...
Then message 15 should be ...

@Then("message $ord should be ...")
public void assertMessage(int ord) {...}
```